# How to alternate row colour when value changes in xslt

Tags: xslt

If I make a xslt report which has rows like this:
When there is a change in the value in the column the row color or font color should change. How to do that ? I tried grouping was that was not successfull.

```
123  - white row colour
123  - white row colour
876  - grey row colour
848  - white row colour
543  - grey row colour
543  - grey row colour
543  - grey row colour
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to/cannot use CSS to solve this or are confined to XSLT 1.0 (no `<xsl:for-each-group group-adjacent...>`), then this problem can be solved iteratively. To alternate row colors properly, it must be known for every row which color was picked for the row before it.

Iteration in XSLT is done through recursion: Call a template for the first item, let it figure out a color, and let that template call itself until it runs out of items, passing on the current color with every step.

Assuming this kind of input:

```
<document>
  <data>123</data>
  <data>123</data>
  <data>876</data>
  <data>848</data>
  <data>543</data>
  <data>543</data>
  <data>543</data>
</document>
```

the following program uses this process to alternate colors:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="document">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="data[1]">
        <xsl:call-template name="rows" />  
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="rows">
    <xsl:param name="previous_color" />

    <xsl:variable name="color">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test=". = preceding-sibling::*[1]"><xsl:value-of select="$previous_color" /></xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$previous_color = 'white'">grey</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>white</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <data color="{$color}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></data>

    <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::*[1]">
      <xsl:call-template name="rows">
        <xsl:with-param name="previous_color" select="$color" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and produces

```
<document>
  <data color="white">123</data>
  <data color="white">123</data>
  <data color="grey">876</data>
  <data color="white">848</data>
  <data color="grey">543</data>
  <data color="grey">543</data>
  <data color="grey">543</data>
</document>
```

Note that the `<xsl:for-each>` is only used with a single node every time. All that does is change the "current node" (`.`) from one `<data>` to the next, and of course it prevents endless recursion in the last step.

Comment: This does not work. I need to have all the rows with the same number with the grey colour. Now it knows when the number changes but they are not with the same row colour.

Answer (score 0):

If the target format is HTML then one way is to group your adjacent rows into `tbody` elements and to delegate the alternating background color styling to CSS with

```
        tbody:nth-child(odd) {
          background-color: white;
        }
        tbody:nth-child(even) {
          background-color: grey;
        }
```

Grouping on the adjacent value of the first column is done in XSLT 2 or 3 easily with `for-each-group group-adjacent`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>.NET XSLT Fiddle Example</title>
        <style>
            tbody:nth-child(odd) {
              background-color: white;
            }
            tbody:nth-child(even) {
              background-color: grey;
            }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="data">
      <table>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-adjacent="col[1]">
              <tbody>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </tbody>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
      <tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="col">
      <td>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </td>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv8g